# How to override a function without redefine in c#?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a requirement where I have a class and a function

```
   public  class BaseClass
        {
            public virtual int MyMethod(int n)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BaseClass=" + n + "+" + 2);
                return n + 2;
            }
        }
```

and a derived class b
where I am extending the base class function

```
 public class A : BaseClass
        {
            public override int MyMethod(int n)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Class A=" + n+"*"+2);
                return n*2;
            }
        }
```

In the derived class when I call the function  A.MyMethod() 
 the base function should be executed followed by the derived class function.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            A classA = new A();
            A.MyMethod(1);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You need to be clearer in your requirements. It doesn't help that your original code doesn't compile.

Comment: Please look at the updated code.

Comment: That still wouldn't compile - you'd want to call `classA.MyMethod` instead. And if you want to call the base class method first, then simply make `A.MyMethod` do that - start the implementation with `base.MyMethod(n)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you want to call the base constructor from the derived constructor? Yes, you can do that with the base() construct.

```
public Derived(int sides)
    : base(sides)
```

When Square() actually isn't a constructor (it is in your question, no return type or void) but a method, you can do it like this:

```
public override returntype Foo(...)
{
    // your adaptation
    base.Foo(...)
```

The method in the base class has to be virtual for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
class b: a
{   
    public new int Square(int n)
    {
      var baseResult = base.Square(n);
      var i = 0//extenting the code
      return i;
    }
}
```